# How to rearrange equations with a magnitude sign?

Tags: absolute-value

There is probably something dreadfully simple I am missing here, but in the derivation of the speeds after a collision of any elasticity, there is a step that involves going from:

$$C_r = \frac{|v_2 - v_1|}{|u_1 - u_2|}$$

... to this:

$$v_2 = v_1 + C_r(u_1 - u_2)$$

... where $C_r$ is the coefficient of restitution, $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the initial velocities of two particles and $v_1$ and $v_2$ are their final velocities.

How is it legal to rearrange the equation as seen above? What happened to the magnitudes that had been taken?

Thank you.

([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution#Speeds_after_impact) is an example of this derivation)

Comment: I get $v_2 = v_1 \pm C_r(u_1 - u_2)$.

Comment: @Dan yes thank you that's what I thought too!!! I am not going crazy...! Perhaps one of the solutions was ignored as it ended up being unphysical

Comment: The other solution is the balls not colliding and carrying on their original paths.